C# Console App Files apprear to be untracked in my repository C_Sharp
enter image description here# (base) sangth@Sangs-MacBook-Pro C_Sharp % git status
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   .DS_Store
deleted:    CSharpFirstProject/.DS_Store
deleted:    CSharpFirstProject/.vs/CSharpFirstProject/xs/UserPrefs.xml
Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
CSharpProject_1/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(base) sangth@Sangs-MacBook-Pro C_Sharp %
please help! I am trying to start on my C# .net project, but the files I created in Visual Studio appeared untracked inside the directory folder

This seems like more of a Git question than a c# question.

Make sure the .git folder (in windows explore click View > and check Hidden items if you can't see it) is in the same folder as your project/solution and the files aren't excluded by .gitignore
